# Windows 10: Docker exits containers immediately

Tags: windows, docker

First I install Docker via Desktop Installer.
Then I test run

`docker run hello-world`
or
`docker run -it -p 8091:8091 hello-world`

I try linux containers and windows containers. The result is always the same: containers get created and immediately exited.

`docker container ls --all`
shows, using windows containers:

```
C:\Users\lruland>docker container ls --all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
78e1c44209b7        hello-world         "cmd /C 'type C:\\hel…"   4 seconds ago       Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                       sharp_jones
```

using linux containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
a90826bdf0f5        hello-world            "/hello"            17 seconds ago      Exited (0) 16 seconds ago                       cocky_darwin
```

Comment: paste container logs here. docker logs <container-id>

Comment: I am facing the same issue with Windows containers. Container exits shortly after command line prompt appears. The output is simply:
> docker logs 13175e2bf24f
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1607]
> (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common misconception with people starting with Docker.

The container exited because it finished its work: outputting hello world, that's why the exit code is 0 and not 1 for example. The container exited successfully.

If you check the dockerfile for the hello-world image [here](https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world/blob/master/amd64/hello-world/Dockerfile#L3), you can see this line:

```
CMD ["/hello"]
```

It means that once you start a container with that image, it will just run the `hello` binary which is compiled form this [hello.c](https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world/blob/master/hello.c) file. And all it does is just display a message and exits.
If you try another image for example `redis`, it would not exit because the process that is started is a long-running one.

Answer (score 2):

`hello-world` container is supposed to print "Hello World" and exit immediately. So this is an expected behavior.

Docker containerizes your application but the lifecycle of the application is application specfic.

Try container that actually runs some server and you'll see that it doesn't exit immediately